# C# ObjectListView flicker on refreshobject

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I use ObjectListView which is great in general but I found a problem which bugs me because it's a visual bug. I have a method which runs like every 2 second and updates some columns with current time based on conditions. But after I update the object and use RefreshObject method the row get default backcolor for a fractal of time and get his row color back and this makes flicker. If I don't do RefreshObject it updates my model inside that row but not visually. The way I get row item is this :

```
rowItem GG = OLVa.GetItem(i).RowObject as rowItem;
GG.Time = "something";
OLVa.Refreshobject(GG);
```

and the way I color the row is this :

```
OLVa.GetItem(i).BackColor = Color.Pink;
```

After I change backcolor of rows based on conditions I just use `OLVa.Refresh();`

I'm not sure what I do wrong coloring the row or updating the row?

Answer (score 2):

**Solving your problem**

The problem is using `GetItem` which returns the UI control element. With object list view you are supposed to do everything based on the objects and not change the actual Control elements.  Basically you are fighting against the API with this approach instead of working with it.

I think what you should use is `RowFormatter` to set the background colour:

```cs
OLVa.RowFormatter = (o) =>
{
    if(o.RowObject == "B")
        o.BackColor = Color.Pink;
};
```

**Reproducing Your Problem**

I was able to reproduce the problem you describe using the following (bad) code.  It creates a flicker like you describe:

```cs
public class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
        // 
        // MainForm
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

        var OLVa = new ObjectListView();
        OLVa.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        OLVa.Columns.Add(new OLVColumn("Name", "ToString"));
        this.Controls.Add(OLVa);

        OLVa.AddObject("A");
        OLVa.AddObject("B");
        OLVa.AddObject("C");

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 100;
        t.Tick += (s,e)=>OLVa.RefreshObject("B");
        t.Start();

        Timer t2 = new Timer();
        t2.Interval = 200;
        t2.Tick += (s,e)=>OLVa.GetItem(1).BackColor = Color.Pink;
        t2.Start();
    }
}
```

Changing the second timer to the row formatter fixed the problem.

**Changing Row Highlighting Based On Condition**

Calling `RefreshObject` automatically triggers `RowFormatter` and aspects so if you want to change the state of a row over time (e.g. as you requested in comment) you could do something like this:

```cs
    public class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
            // 
            // MainForm
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
            this.Name = "MainForm";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

            var OLVa = new FastObjectListView();
            OLVa.Width = 250;
            OLVa.Height = 250;
            OLVa.Columns.Add(new OLVColumn("Done", "Done"));
            OLVa.Columns.Add(new OLVColumn("Percent", "PercentComplete"));

            this.Controls.Add(OLVa);

            Video v = new Video();

            OLVa.AddObject(v);

            var t = new Timer();
            t.Interval = 1000;
            t.Start();

            OLVa.RowFormatter = (s) => s.BackColor = ((Video) s.RowObject).Done ? Color.Green : Color.Red;

            t.Tick += (s,e)=>
            {
                v.PercentComplete = Math.Min(v.PercentComplete += 10, 100);
                if (v.PercentComplete == 100)
                    v.Done = true;

                OLVa.RefreshObject(v);
            };

        }

        private class Video
        {
            public bool Done { get; set; }
            public int PercentComplete { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay I have return my paint method which I'm painting with GetItem, but now my item's color does not change. RowFormatter works only for first time when I add a new item if I understand it correctly.
"This delegate can be used to format a OLVListItem before it is added to the control."
I need this way to work in certain situations like user interactions and a few other things, can you help me how? As example if I have videos in my objectlistview and I want to re-color my items after videos is done how do I achieve that? Like played items will be red, current one green and rest yellow

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how to recolour rows.  Basically it boils down to just calling `RefreshObject` and that's it.

Comment: With ObjectListView you pretty much never want to do your own drawing (at least not the Windows Forms veriety).  You set up the rules (e.g. formatter, aspect getters etc) then add the objects and if an object changes you call `RefreshObject`.  And in fact `RowFormatter` also fires under other circumstances (e.g. when mouse enters the row).  It's good practice to assume that that method will be firing pretty regularly (so don't put any expensive operations in it) but to make sure to call `RefreshObject` if you know your object state has changed in a meaningful way.

Comment: Thank you for trying, I use normal objectlistview instead of fastobjectlistview and with 1200 item it take too much time, while using SubItem coloring setting the Start Times take 1300-1500 millisecond which is not perfect but tolerable but when I switch my model to work with INotifyPropertyChanged and update my start time value it take 4000-4700 millisecond. So I will use kind of hybrid solution, for my start times(Which set every 2 second) I'll use normal listview and for other things I don't update much I'll use ObjectListView